# PHP Looping through dates

Tags: php, date, loops

I have the following while loop which compares 2 dates to see if 1 is less than another, and if not then it adds a week to the first date.

It works fine, however where there is a greater difference between the dates (i.e. greater than 12 months) I get a timeout error as it has passed the max execution time.

Can anyone help me make this more efficient?

```
        while($startDate->timestamp < $current_week->timestamp){
            $data['weeks'][$w] = array(
                'monday' => $startDate->startofWeek()->format('d/m/Y'), 
                'sunday' => $startDate->endofWeek()->format('d/m/Y')
            );
            $w++;
            $startDate = $startDate->addDays(7); // Move it on to the following week
        }
```

I should add that I'm working with the Carbon API extension for DateTime

Thanks

----Edit----

Something strange is happening that I don't understand. If I pass a date hard coded to $startDate everything after 2013-01-06 works fine (and fast) but as soon as goes after this date it times out. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: This means that executing your script takes longer than what is set in set_time_limit (30 sec by default). You may want to take a look at your script again to make it faster, or you can set set_time_limit to a greater value.

Comment: @Ronald01990 yes I know that, I was just asking that without changing the set_time how can I make the loop more effiecient. Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to create that array?

Comment: @Ashalynd I use the arrays to give headings to the tables I use to display date for that given week.

Comment: Sorry I delete my answqer because I was wrong... Why do you want an array with all weeks between two dates? What are you trying to do with it? What is the final HTML? image?

Comment: But you will create e.g. 54 entries if dates have year difference. Are all 54 needed?

Comment: @Ashalynd Yes I need to show every single week between the 2 dates

Comment: @JoDev This is something like what I want to output https://www.evernote.com/shard/s97/sh/e4192077-788b-48de-a481-4bc3a4b276f0/4d5195075cbf9d7960eb9ffceba0045e

Comment: Your code is working, you are probably doing something extra in the loop. [See example of the same code](https://eval.in/57743), just without Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing a little more to `$startDate` than you expect - you're modifying the object with `->startOfWeek()` and `->endOfWeek()` rather than just calculating the string output; my reading of the source to [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php) is that every method you call modifies the object, so the assignment in the last line of your while loop is unnecessary (it could just as easily be written as `$startDate->addDays(7);`. As a result of that your code is a little bit less efficient than it could be, and might even loop one or two times more than you want.

However, I would suspect this block of code isn't your real problem, and that it's further down your codebase - if your problems grow with the size of $data['weeks'] then it's probably something in the way in which you're processing it for your HTML.

Comment: It's just something I have to live with for the second, however, it's actually becoming a thing with me that I need to find out why it times out on a particular date (see edit above). You're right about the addDays function but it still works as it should no matter it I passed addDays(1) or addDays(7)